# Solve differential equation $\left((1-x^2)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-2x\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{n^2}{1-x^2}\right)y(x)=0$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I have to solve the differential equation
$$\left((1-x^2)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-2x\frac{d}{dx}-\frac{n^2}{1-x^2}\right)y(x)=0$$
In order to solve above differential equation I have substitution i.e. if we let
$$z=\ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}$$

This substitution can solve the above differential equation,but I don't know how we suppose this substitution, and what is basic concept behind this substitution.

Is there any best method to solve this differential equation (any other substitution), if I face any other such type of differential equation?

Comment: The equation in the body is different from the title. Also, is it assumed that $y = y(x)$?

Comment: Is it done now?

Comment: Now it is good    :)

Comment: Now please any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, your equation is of Sturm-Liouville form $\frac{d}{dx}[(1-x^2)\frac{dy}{dx}] - \frac{n^2}{1-x^2}y = 0$. This can be seen by applying the integrating factor approach to the first two terms of the equations, and seeing that $(1-x^2)$ is exactly the integrating factor. There is an entire theory devoted to solving exactly this kind of equations.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory

Sorry, I've never seen a substitution for the parameter variable used for an ODE solution. Surely, to see this clearly the equation needs to be transformed, and that is already half of the solution. I suspect this is one of those olympiad problems, where somebody discovered this approach by accident, without using it within any formal solution protocol, and then used to troll poor students

Comment: Yes, I have posted question above is a Sturm-Liouville equation and the problem was for finding the Green function. I just posted the differential equation. Thanks for your answer. This is very help full for me.

Comment: But still the problem I have to solve the above differential equation. Why we assume such substitution? And is there any other way to solve the above DE?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume the form $$
y(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k
$$
and assume $a_0=0$, and $a_1=q$ for some constant $q$. Then the solution follows that $a_{2n}=0$ and otherwise 
$$
a_k = \frac{q P_{k-1}(n)}{k!}
$$
with
$$
P_0(n)=1\\
P_2(n)=(2+n^2)\\
P_4(n)=(24+20n^2+n^4)\\
P_6(n)=(720+784n^2+70n^4+n^6)\\
\cdots
$$
the coeffieicients of the temrs in the $P_k(n)$ seem to be wholly descibed by the table [A111594 in the OEIS](https://oeis.org/A111594/table). These coefficients are made by even powers on the exponential generating functions
$$
\frac{\tanh^{-2k-1}(x)}{(2k+1)!}
$$

Comment: Seems to be new for me. What is this method?